# iPhone OpenGL: Moving around a 3D environment

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, 3d

this is probably a long shot

I am looking for an example / tutorial of how to render a floor (or room) and move around it.  There seems to be the perfect example here:
http://www.cocoachina.com/wiki/index.php?title=OpenGL_ES_13_-_Moving_in_3D

However the download (which is required) is missing.

Does anyone have any code samples for OpenGL 3D and moving around 3D Space

Answer (score 0):

Look at the SIO2 package.  There is a tutorial for moving a camera around a room, works out of the box.  I forget exactly now but I think it's tutorial 06 or 07.  He also puts videos explaining them on YouTube, which is nice.

Comment: Last I heard, the cost was $50 if you wanted to use it in an App Store app.

Comment: After playing with raw OpenGL ES last night for quite a few hours and achieving a triangle, I think I will look at SIO2